# SGD object has no attribute minimize

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am new to Tensorflow2, so I hope the question is not too basic, and I am following the exercises from https://github.com/Apress/Machine-Learning-for-Economics-and-Finance-in-TensorFlow-2.

One of the exercises it to a minimize a function using SGD and my code returned (it worked and then suddenly it stopped): "'SGD' object has no attribute 'minimize'". The same happens if I try to replicate the the example from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer (Usage):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as keras

print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)

print(tf.optimizers.SGD)

# Create an optimizer with the desired parameters.
opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
var1, var2 = tf.Variable(1.0), tf.Variable(2.0)
# `loss` is a callable that takes no argument and returns the value
# to minimize.
loss = lambda: 3 * var1 * var1 + 2 * var2 * var2
# Call minimize to update the list of variables.
opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1, var2])
```

I am running Tensorflow 2.16.0-dev20240108 and Keras 3.0.3.dev2024010903.

As I said, I am new to it, so any help is much appreciated.

I checked other posts/questions on Stack Overflow, but no solution came up. I also updated Tensorflow and Keras. I was expecting the code to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)

# Create an optimizer with the desired parameters.
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
var1, var2 = tf.Variable(1.0), tf.Variable(2.0)
# `loss` is a callable that takes no argument and returns the value
# to minimize.
loss = lambda: 3 * var1 * var1 + 2 * var2 * var2
# Call minimize to update the list of variables.
opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1, var2])
```

This code uses TensorFlow's integrated Keras API, which should resolve the issue.